# Problem with <picture> tag and responsive images

Tags: html, image, picturebox, responsive-images, srcset

I'm new to this world and I'm learning by myself with the "Learning Web Design" book by Jennifer Robbins.

I got in the "Responsive images" chapter. After reading everything was clear but when I tried the exercise things got tricky.

The exercise on the book asked me to replace 3  tags from a previous page and replace them with a  tag and a set of three files for each image (400, 800 & 1200px).

The code on the book is this:

```
<picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 640px)"
                srcset="images/bread-800.jpg 800w,
                        images/bread-1200.jpg 1200w"
                sizes="80vw">
        <img src="images/bread-400.jpg" alt="close-up of sliced rustic bread">
</picture>
```

I tried it and checked with Chrome developer tools but I can't see the 800px image file. For <640px width  the browser gets the 400px file. And for >=640px widths it uses the 1200px files.

I also uploaded the page on GitHub at [david0495.github.io/gallery.html](https://david0495.github.io/gallery.html) and tried XRespond.
Here is a screenshot of the result:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6lmK.jpg)

At last, I tried to open the page on Chrome with a resized window. Enlarging the windows I can see finally see the 800px file. But I'm not understanding at which size it activates and why I can't see it on developer tools.

I'm getting crazy with these thing. Hope someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: After trying for days to understand the browser's criteria for choosing between the images in srcset attribute it seems that the browser (I used Chrome) changes the image when the device's viewport is half the arithmetic mean of the two largest file widths. I tried a lot of different file sets and different values for the sizes attribute. So in this example I have: ((1200-800)/2+800)/2=500/80vw=625px...The browser switches between the two files at 613px exactly. At last it seems that the media condition is irrilevant.

Comment: To be exact after using different files with different dimensions, the result is that the viewport size at which the browser changes the file seems to be always between 0,482 and 0,497 times the arithmetic mean between the widths of the largest files. I can't still understand why but at least this is useful for choosing the desired configuration. If someone knows something else about this I would appreciate.